# Update display of hierarchical data using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have hierarchical data, which I display as nested lists using D3. The top level is fixed, but the child level is a list of counters which change. Not only the counted values, but also the number of counters change over time. I start with data like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        'id': 'id_1',
        'counts': d3.map()
    },
    {
        'id': 'id_2',
        'counts': d3.map()
    }
];
```

Initially this should just be displayed as

```html
<ul>
  <li>id_1</li>
  <li>id_2</li>
</ul>
```

Now time flies and I get some counted values in, which I simulate with this function:

```
var time_flies = function() {
    data[0].counts.set('counter_1', 1);
    data[1].counts.set('counter_2', 5);
    data[1].counts.set('counter_3', 8);
}
```

I tried to render this using D3 using the following code:

var main = d3.select('body').append('ul');

```
var render = function() {
    main.selectAll('li')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append('li')
            .html(function(n) { return n.id; })
            .append('ul').selectAll('li')
                .data(function(n) {
                    return n.counts.entries();
                })
                .enter()
                    .append('li')
                    .html(function(n) {
                        return n.key + ': ' + n.value;})
        ;
};
```

The following works fine:

```
time_flies();
render();
```

But what I really need its:

```
render();
time_flies();
render();
```

Obviously I managed to get the one-time static solution working, but I need to update the display whenever the counters update. I'm aware, that I have to move some code from the `enter()` section into the `update` one, but I did not manage to do so. The tricky part is probably the second `<ul>`, but I don't get where and how to create it, so the structure can be updated with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the old data when calling render + you need to do an update.

```
var render = function() {

    var lis = main.selectAll('li')
        .data(data);
        //for removing removed data
        lis.exit().remove()
        //for appending new data if any
        lis.enter()
            .append('li');
        //for update
        main.selectAll('li')
            .html(function(n) { return n.id; })
            .append('ul').selectAll('li')
                .data(function(n) {
                    return n.counts.entries();
                })
                .enter()
                    .append('li')
                    .html(function(n) {
                        return n.key + ': ' + n.value;})
        ;
};
```

Comment: Seems to work, but don't get why!? My top level structure does not change, so why is `lis.exit()` relevant at all and triggered? From my point of view, no `<li>` or attached data is exiting!?

Comment: Ok if the data set length is not altered then you can skip the exit section. The  update section is updating the values.  If you use it in association with enter then the update does not work.